# How to remove autofocus from first input field in PageBlockTable?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a page block table :

```
<apex:pageBlock id="adressInput" mode="maindetail">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <apex:outputLabel for="street" styleClass="control-label col-md-2">
                    Street
                </apex:outputLabel>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <apex:inputText id="street" value="{!searchParameters.street}" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Street..." onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { searchAddress(); return false; }" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

By default, the focus is set to the first available inputField. In my case, the first input is a text field(**`street`**). Every time I go to the page, the focus is set to that field.

How to remove that autofocus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this Code in your VF Page. It will remove the autofocus for all the fields and will put the focus on any field that you want

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        jQuery('input[type=text]').blur();
        /*
        //For putting the Focus on particular field
        jQuery('[id$=pList]').focus();
        */
    };
</script>
```

Hope this might helps...